# Intellij keeps re-ordering my `import os`

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble understanding Intellij's import policy for python for `import os`. As far as I know, the import order is supposed to be `standard library` first, then `third party packages`, then `company packages`, and finally `intra-package or relative imports`.  For the most part Intellij orders everything correctly, but keeps pushing `import os` into third party packages. Am I missing smth? Isn't `import os` a standard library package?

Answer (score 2):

It might happen if the corresponding module comes from a virtual environment that itself is located inside a project directory, and it confuses the detection of the right import group. There was [a similar request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18970) in the tracker, but it was fixed quite a while ago. Which version of Python plugin do you use? Would you mind creating a dedicated issue in YouTrack so that we could investigate the problem further there?

Comment: thanks for the reply: python plugin for intellij: version: 2017.1.171.3780.116. I switched SDKs with one without a virtualenv and the same happens.   also created a ticket in YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23857

Answer (score 1):

The answer I got from a co-worker a couple of years age is that **os** was originally a third-party package; IntelliJ left it where it is for some backward compatibility issue.